# Achieving persistence through JBPM KIE workbench console

Tags: java, workflow, jbpm, workflow-engine

I have created a sample business process to resemble needs of my organizational use case.
This use case deals with objects such as Employee, Room, Department etc.I have created these  entities as data models using KIE workbench.

Can anyone tell me how can i persist these POJOs/entities ? How to configure jBPM engine to enable persistence via console?

Answer (score 0):

If you used the Data Modeler the POJOS will be marked as serializable (implement the Serializable interface) and your models will be ready for persistence.

You just need to define process variables of the type of your classes and the entities will be automatically persisted as you modify them during the process execution, in script tasks for example.